# Unix cat starting from line

Tags: command-line, cat

What is the best way to output from a file starting from a specific line (big number like 70000). Something like:

```
cat --line=70000 <file>
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Take a look at tail, more precisecly, it's --lines=+N switch:

```
tail --lines=+100 <file>
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know this even after using this on linux for 8 years ! I always used a bash fn ! Thanks ! 

getFromLine () { lineno=`wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}'` ; lineno=`expr $lineno - $2` ; tail -n $lineno $1 ; }

Comment: As a note, this does not work on Mountain Lion (Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0). The variant for Mountain lion is `tail -n`

Answer (score 25):

The most obvious way is `tail`. The syntax might be slightly different depending on what OS you are using:

```
tail -n +70000
```

If you can not get `tail` to work, you could use `sed`, but it might end up slower:

```
sed -pe '1,69999d'
```

Comment: `tail` worked just fine in [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) (on a 600 MB text file). The runtime was only a few seconds (but the input file could have been in the file cache already).

Answer (score 6):

You can use **NR** parameter with the **awk** command:

```
cat <file> | awk '{if (NR>=7000) print}'
```

Comment: You can use this command with other limits. As a sample:`cat messages | awk '{if (NR>=7000 && NR <7003) print}'` shows you row 7000, 7001 and 7002 only.

Answer (score 4):

If instead of a line number you need to start listing at the line containing a given `$phrase`, try the following.

```
more -1000 +/"$phrase" yourfilename | sed '1,4d'
```

The -1000 will continuously list text for up to 1000 lines; you can change this as needed.
The `sed` command will chop off the first 4 lines of output, which were automatically inserted by `more`, containing a blank line, the message "... skipping", and the two lines preceding your intended starting line. I guess this may vary depending on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tail +250 <file_name>
```